# как выбрать первый впереди стояший элемент с определеным атрибутом

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<ul >
    <li data-depth="0" >1</li>
    <li data-depth="0" >2</li>
    <li data-depth="1" >3</li>
    <li data-depth="1" >4</li>
    <li data-depth="0" >5</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
var item //в этой переменной находится <li data-depth="1" >4</li>
```

мне из него надо получить `<li data-depth="0" >2</li>` пытаюсь сделать так

```
var classDeptch = item.attr('data-depth');
    if(classDeptch>0){
       var siblingItemDepht = Number(classDeptch)-Number(1);
       var parent=item.siblings('[data-depth='+siblingItemDepht+']');
      console.log(parent);
    }
```

но получаю три `li` мне же надо получить первый впереди `li` то есть вот этот  `<li data-depth="0" >2</li>`

Comment: т.е вам всегда нужно будет получать первый элемент с  data-depth="0" ?

Comment: @Arsen первый впереди стоящий элемент с data-depth="0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте `prevAll()`, чтобы выбрать "впереди стоящие" элементы, потом `.first()`, чтобы выбрать первый из списка (prevAll "перевернут")

и раз уж используете jquery используйте метод `data()` (без jquery есть dataset)

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  var item = $(this);
  item.siblings().removeClass('parent');
  var classDeptch = item.data('depth');
  if (classDeptch > 0) {
    var siblingItemDepht = Number(classDeptch) - Number(1);
    var parent = item.prevAll('[data-depth=' + siblingItemDepht + ']').first();
    parent.addClass('parent');
    console.log(parent);
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-depth="0">1</li>
  <li data-depth="0">2</li>
  <li data-depth="1">3</li>
  <li data-depth="1">4</li>
  <li data-depth="0">5</li>
  <li data-depth="2">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: у меня получается вообще первый,  а нужен первый впереди стоящий li с атрибутом data depth меньшим на 1 , то-есть если использовать ваш код  мне при нажатии на `<li data-depth="1">3</li>` или `<li data-depth="1">4</li>` надо  чтобы выбирался `<li data-depth="0">2</li>` а после выбора `<li data-depth="2">6</li>`  выбирался `<li data-depth="0">5</li>` правда `<li data-depth="2">6</li>` должен иметь такой вид `<li data-depth="1">6</li>`

Comment: в смысле ближайший ?

Comment: у вас там -1, поэтому я привел пример, где выбираются сиблинги с data-depth, иначе можно было бы не использовать siblingItemDepht, изменил пример

Comment: спасибо большое все работает.